# When $8$ people are selected from two groups, what is the probability that exactly $6$ of them are selected from group A?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a problem with solving the following task:

There are 10 people in group A and 9 in group B, we are selecting 8 people in total. What is the probability of exactly six (6) in group A being selected?

I know i should use unordered selection without repossession, but I do not know how. Should I use Binomial coefficient and how?

I have attempted doing: ((6!/10!)*(2!/9!))/(19!/8!)

Thank you!

Comment: This is not clear.  How are we selecting people?  If we only select one person, the answer is $0$.  Please edit your post for clarity and to include your efforts.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! [It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: I have added my efforts, it is my first post on this page. Thank you for your understanding :)

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  I assume we are to choose "randomly", i.e. "every group of $8$ is as likely to be chosen as any other".  Your answer is correct IF you mean *exactly* $6$.  However, you might mean *at least* $6$ in which case you have to consider the cases in which $7$ or $8$ people from $A$ are chosen.  There's no way for us to guess which meaning you  (or whomever set the question) had in mind.

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly 6 :) If I was going to calculatoe between 5-7 in gorup B, would I use a similar method and multiply the answer for the probability of 5,6 and 7 in group B?

Comment: Have a look at [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: Take a look at [this question and the Hypergeometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458755/probability-of-a-probability-to-happen/2458775#2458775) to see where the binomial coefficient comes in.

Comment: Then your answer is correct in spirit, but you should replace your terms with binomial coefficients.  The total number of selections is $\binom {19}8$ for example, with similar corrections in the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\text{Probability}=\frac{\binom{10}{6}\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{19}{8}}.
$$